# firebase multi path update and rules for each path

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm implementing a users and events system. One restriction is that a user can only host 1 event at a time.

I initially tried to implement the restriction by querying the `events` node in the `events` `.write` rule, by looking for an event that already had a userId equal to `auth.uid`. But i couldn't figure out how to do that, so i decided to create a new node, `hosts`, as a lookup table. It just stores any userIds that are currently hosting an event. If a user tries to create a event, and their userId already exists in `hosts`, then it's an error.

Rules:

```
{
  "rules":{
        "users":{
            "$uid":{
                ".read": "auth.uid == $uid",
              ".write": "auth.uid == $uid",
              ".validate": "newData.exists()"
          }
      },
      "hosts":{
            "$uid":{
                ".read": "true",
                //to be a host, you must be a user
              ".write": "auth.uid == $uid &&    root.child('users').hasChild(auth.uid) &&   !root.child('hosts').hasChild(auth.uid)",
              ".validate": "newData.exists()"
          }
      },
      "events":{
          "$uid":{
                ".read": "true",
                //to create an event, you must be a host
              ".write": "root.child('hosts').hasChild(auth.uid)",
              ".validate": "true"
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Javascript:

```
createEvent(form){
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser
    var db = firebase.database();
    var newEventRef = db.ref('events').push();
    var newEvent = {}
    newEvent[uid] = form*/

    var update = {
        ['hosts/'+user.uid]: true
        update['events/'+newEventRef.key] = form
    };
    db.ref().update(update)
        .then((...args)=>{
            ...
        })
        .catch(err=>{
            ...
        })
},
```

The problem with the update call is that it always fails. I'm trying to insert into `hosts` and `events` at the same time. But the `events` `write` rule expects the userId to be in `hosts` before it writes, so i guess that's why it fails.

Do i have to make 2 separate updates? 1 to insert userId into `hosts`, and then if that succeeds, another insert into `events`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In security rules there are three variables that refer to the data:

- `data` - the data as it exists at the location of the rule *before* it is updated
- `newData` - the data as it exists at the location of the rule *after* it is updated
- `root` - the data as it exists at the root of thd database *before* it is updated

So when you refer to `root` in your rules, you get the data from before the update. To get the updated data, you have to refer to `newData`. Since unfortunately there is no `newRoot`, you will have to navigate from `newData` up to the required level by calling `parent()` multiple times.

Once example:

```
  "events":{
      "$uid":{
            ".read": "true",
            //to create an event, you must be a host
          ".write": "newData.parent().parent().child('hosts').hasChild(auth.uid)",
          ".validate": "true"
      }
  }
```

Comment: This helped me solve a 2 hour issue, was not aware of the relative path situation for newData, very nice and simple explanation, used parent() to fix :)